# #ifdef #else - neither branch chosen

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following code

```
#if defined(TESTING)
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC(...) TestFailed(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_UNIT_TEST(...) TestFailedInUnitTest(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC(...)
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_UNIT_TEST(...)
#endif
```

and make a call `TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC(peripheral, testSuiteName, testName, 
                                    "Internal coding error; bad state (%d)", state);`

and the compiler complians that `testSuiteName` and `testName` are not defined - even though `#TESTING` is not defined.

[Update] The compiler also says `"Error 3   implicit declaration of function 'TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC'`

---

[Update] Please ignore veryting below this line. The problem is above. Thanks.

So, I tried this [Update] `else` should be `#else`, then I am told that `TESTING` is not defiend. SO, why is the code above not working?

```
#if defined(TESTING)
#error "Testing is defined <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
wf
else
#error "Testing is NOT defined <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
eyh6
#endif

#ifdef TESTING
#error "Testing is defined @@"
ehye
else
#error "Testing is NOT defined @@"
5he567
#endif

#error "Sample error ###"
```

and the only error the compiler gave was `Error 3   #error "Sample error ###"`

Any idea what is going wrong? (Atmel AVR Studio, which is based on Microsoft Visual studio`.

Many, many, many other `#if defined` are working just fine ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `#` before the `else`s.

EDIT:
For the real question you added, I've tried the following code which does compile and run without any problem in gcc 4.5.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(TESTING)
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC(...) TestFailed(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_UNIT_TEST(...) TestFailedInUnitTest(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC(...)
#define TEST_FAILED_IN_UNIT_TEST(...)
#endif

int main()
{
        TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC
        (
                peripheral
                , testSuiteName
                , testName
                , "Internal coding error; bad state (%d)"
                , state
        );
        printf("Test successful\n");
        return 0;
}
```

So, what compiler (and what version) are you using?

Comment: +1 @shinkou - but only in the second piece of code. When I add it I get `Error 3 #error "Testing is NOT defined`.  But the real problem is the top pieceof code. Why is the compiler complaining that `testSuiteName` and `testName` are not defined - even though #TESTING is not defined?

Comment: Your code works for me too  (Atmel AVR Studio, which is based on Microsoft Visual studio). But my code does not (it does work in NEtBEans using GCC.   The only compile errors I get, after clean & build, have to do with `testName` and `testSuitName`, except fot the inexplicable `Error 5 implicit declaration of function 'TEST_FAILED_IN_VMC'` - solve that and it will work. But, how?

Comment: @Mawg I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you could define the functions to `0` in the `#else` block and see.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `else`, use `#else` to use the correct preprocessor directive.

Comment: +1 @nafziger - but only in the second piece of code. When I add it I get `Error 3 #error "Testing is NOT defined`.  But the real problem is the top pieceof code. Why is the compiler complaining that `testSuiteName` and `testName` are not defined - even though #TESTING is not defined?